# Silverlight, "The type or namespace name 'CookieContainer' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net'"

Tags: silverlight, .net-4.0

I'm running VS2010 pro, [and I downloaded a sample Silverlight app](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/03/17/silverlight-2-beta1-wcf-linq-to-sql-a-powerfull-combination.aspx) written in an older version.  I did the conversion but now when I go to run it, I get this error.  I searched the net, the only recommendation I found was to add a reference to "System.Net" (which didn't make sense, but I did anyway), but this didn't help.  The offending code:

```
public System.Net.CookieContainer CookieContainer {...
```

Answer (score 1):

The System.Net dll is usually referenced by default but perhaps it wasn't in the older project.   Check the version number is 2.0.5.0 and that the file path is something like:-

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\System.Net.dll

Answer (score 0):

> CookieContainer Class Namespace: 
>   System.Net Assembly:  System (in
>   System.dll) Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1

CookieContainer still exists.

Try deleting the reference in your project then add System.net again.